# QUIZ: 3 Variables, only 1 if-else to print the difference

Tags: variables, if-statement

I got question. How is it possible to solve a problem where I can only use `1` `if-else` statement to check `3` variables which one of them is different and print this?

Example:

```
A = 10
B = 3
C = 10

Answer: B
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify a language, so this is kinda pseudocode:

```
if (A == B) {
    echo 'C';
} elseif (A == C) {
    echo 'B';
} else {
    echo 'A';
}
```

If **A** and **B** are equal, we know the different one is **C**.
Otherwise, if **A** and **C** are equal, the different one is **B**.
**C** and **B** aren't the problem? We're only left with **A**.

Answer (score 0):

In C language it would like this:

```
int A = 10;
int B = 5;
int C = 10;

if ( A == B)            //  Check A and B for Equality 
    printf ("Answer: C");  
else if (A == C)        //  Check A and C for Equality
    printf ("Answer: B");
else                    // Then the answer must be A
    printf ("Answer: A");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a answer to this! Also I forgot to mention, you're only allowed to use 1 if and else (So no elseifs).

```
if (A == B) {
   print C;
}
else{
   print A + B - C;
}
```